# What is the propre way to configure my small office network (LAN)

Tags: networking, ip-address, router, ethernet, lan

I want some advice, I am trying to set up a network in my small office, which has 20 computers / laptops, 5 printers and a router for the office to have internet access. hardware installation is now complete. my question is do i have to configure an IP address or is it done automatically when connecting the hardware since i'm using the latest version of windows 10? because my goal is for all computers to be connected and able to share files also capable of using the printer.
if anyone can show me a video from youtube on how to do this as i have never done this before but i have some knowledge about ip addresses and masks. because i tried to find myself and there was some ambiguity about the solution i was not sure which video was best for my situation
down bellow is a sketch of my small office:

[image: my office]

Answer (score 0):

> do i have to configure an IP address or is it done automatically when connecting the hardware

You should have a DHCP server that takes care of IP address assignment.

> my goal is for all computers to be connected and able to share files also capable of using the printer

Just connect them all to the same switch, assign addresses via DHCP and you should be set.

If you have no idea how to do that then, seriously, you should hire a professional. You'll need a file server, user policies and backup. You'd also want Internet access and setting up a firewall should never be taken lightly.